# How to host Streamsync server on Windows 10

Tags: python, user-interface

I am investigating using Streamsync to provide a UI for an application. Streamsync provides a UI interface that is accessed from a web browser. I want to serve the application across an intranet (such a 1990s word!). I am able to "host" the demo Streamsync hello application using localhost. I tried to follow the instructions for using uvicorn to serve the application over a local area network.

I am using Visual Studio, and the Python code is as follows:

```
import uvicorn
import streamsync.serve

#app_path = "." # . for current working directory
app_path = "E:\4users\hamilton\dev\Python\GUI\hello" # . for current working directory
mode = "run" # run or edit

asgi_app = streamsync.serve.get_asgi_app(app_path, mode)

uvicorn.run(asgi_app,
    host="0.0.0.0",
    port=5328,
    log_level="warning",
    ws_max_size=streamsync.serve.MAX_WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE_SIZE)
```

When I attempt to run the application, I get an exception (Exception Thrown 3) on the line uvicorn.run(asgi_app,

Can anyone suggest how to host (serve) a Streamsync application on Windows 10 such that another computer on the local area network can access it from a web browser?

***edit***
silly me! double-backslashes needed in app_path.

Now when I run the Python program (Python 3.11), I get the following dump:

> ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "E:\4users\Hamilton\dev\Python\GUI\Streamsync\ssServer\ssServer\ssServerenv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py",
> line 677, in lifespan
> async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:   File "C:\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 204, in **aenter**
> return await anext(self.gen)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "E:\4users\Hamilton\dev\Python\GUI\Streamsync\ssServer\ssServer\ssServerenv\Lib\site-packages\streamsync\serve.py",
> line 42, in lifespan
> app_runner.load()   File "E:\4users\Hamilton\dev\Python\GUI\Streamsync\ssServer\ssServer\ssServerenv\Lib\site-packages\streamsync\app_runner.py",
> line 595, in load
> self._start_app_process()   File "E:\4users\Hamilton\dev\Python\GUI\Streamsync\ssServer\ssServer\ssServerenv\Lib\site-packages\streamsync\app_runner.py",
> line 759, in _start_app_process
> self.app_process.start()   File "C:\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
> self._popen = self._Popen(self)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
> return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in
> _Popen
> return Popen(process_obj)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in
> **init**
> prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 158, in
> get_preparation_data
> _check_not_importing_main()   File "C:\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 138, in
> _check_not_importing_main
> raise RuntimeError(''' RuntimeError:
> An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
> current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
>
> ```
>     This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
>     child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
>     in the main module:
>
>         if __name__ == '__main__':
>             freeze_support()
>             ...
>
>     The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
>     is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
> ```
>
> ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.